# Best way to parse a string to an enum

Tags: go, enums

I have an enum as follows

```golang
type Capability int

const (
    Read   Capability = iota // Read   = 0
    Create                   // Create = 1
    Update                   // Update = 2
    Delete                   // Delete = 3
    List                     // List   = 4
)
```

I want to be able to get the string representation from the enum **AS WELL AS** parse a string to get the enum.

I get the string from the enum as follows.

```golang
capabilityStrs := []string{"read", "create", "update", "delete", "list"}
func (c Capability) String() string {
    return capabilityStrs[c]
}
```

How do I parse a string into an enum such that a call to `ParseSTring("read") gives me` Read`. What is the Best way to go about this?

Comment: I would go with a `map[string]Capability`.

Comment: Thanks! I have done that but is this the best way to go about enums with string representations?

Comment: @prnvbn: What _"defines"_ a best way? do you have some performance constraints?

Comment: @Inian think best was the wrong choice of word, I was hoping to find an idiomatic way of defining enums in go.

Comment: @prnvbn: the map approach as mentioned in the first comment is _the_ idiomatic approach then

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question, but please do so by hitting adding an answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer based on the comment by @super

```golang
var (
    capabilitiesMap = map[string]Capability{
        "read":   Read,
        "create": Create,
        "update": Update,
        "delete": Delete,
        "list":   List,
    }
)
func ParseString(str string) (Capability, bool) {
    c, ok := capabilitiesMap[strings.ToLower(str)]
    return c, ok
}
```

Comment: move the map out of the function. You need not  to re initialize it every time.

Answer (score 5):

This is better than the top answer since if you have a ton of enums, you don't have to write out the list twice (unlike top answer):

```
package usstates

type USState int

//go:generate stringer -type=USState
const (
    Alabama USState = iota
    Alaska
    Arizona
    Arkansas
    California
    Colorado
    Connecticut
    Delaware
    Florida
    Georgia
    Hawaii
    Idaho
    Illinois
    Indiana
    Iowa
    Kansas
    Kentucky
    Louisiana
    Maine
    Maryland
    Massachusetts
    Michigan
    Minnesota
    Mississippi
    Missouri
    Montana
    Nebraska
    Nevada
    NewHampshire
    NewJersey
    NewMexico
    NewYork
    NorthCarolina
    NorthDakota
    Ohio
    Oklahoma
    Oregon
    Pennsylvania
    RhodeIsland
    SouthCarolina
    SouthDakota
    Tennessee
    Texas
    Utah
    Vermont
    Virginia
    Washington
    WestVirginia
    Wisconsin
    Wyoming
)

var MapEnumStringToUSState = func() map[string]USState {
    m := make(map[string]USState)
    for i := Alabama; i <= Wyoming; i++ {
        m[i.String()] = i
    }
    return m
}()
```

Comment: This does not work. 
I get the following error: i.String undefined (type USState has no field or method String)
(You can verify in the Go Playground for example)

Answer (score 2):

Whereas what defines 'best way' is dependable like @inian says, following is one approach

```
type Capability string

const (
    Read   Capability = "READ"
    Create Capability = "CREATE"
    Update Capability = "UPDATE"
    Delete Capability = "DELETE"
    List   Capability = "LIST"
)

func (c Capability)String()string{
    return string(c)
}

func ParseCapability(s string)(c Capability,err error){
    capabilities := map[Capability]struct{}{
        Read: {},
        Create: {},
        Update: {},
        Delete: {},
        List: {},
    }

    cap := Capability(s)
    _,ok := capabilities[cap]
    if !ok{
        return c,fmt.Errorf(`cannot parse:[%s] as capability`,s)
    }
    return cap,nil
}
```